# making sense of confusing perceptron input data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I have the following data:

```
 0 0 0 0 0  0 0
 0 0 0 0 1  0 0
 0 0 0 1 0  0 0
 0 0 0 1 1  0 0
 0 0 1 0 0  0 0
 0 0 1 0 1  0 0
 0 0 1 1 0  0 0
 0 0 1 1 1  1 0
 0 1 0 0 0  0 0
 0 1 0 0 1  0 1
 0 1 0 1 0  0 0
 0 1 0 1 1  1 1
 0 1 1 0 0  0 0
 0 1 1 0 1  1 1
 0 1 1 1 0  1 0
 0 1 1 1 1  1 1
 1 0 0 0 0  0 0
 1 0 0 0 1  0 0
 1 0 0 1 0  0 0
 1 0 0 1 1  1 0
 1 0 1 0 0  0 0
 1 0 1 0 1  1 0
 1 0 1 1 0  1 0
 1 0 1 1 1  1 0
 1 1 0 0 0  0 0
 1 1 0 0 1  1 1
 1 1 0 1 0  1 0
 1 1 0 1 1  1 1
 1 1 1 0 0  1 0
 1 1 1 0 1  1 1
 1 1 1 1 0  1 0
 1 1 1 1 1  1 1
```

And I'm meant to use this as input for a perceptron, viz:

*Implement a 2-layer Perzeptron (one input-layer, one output-layer).*

*The Perzeptron shall have an N-dimensional binary input X, an M-dimensional binary output Y, and a BIAS-weight for implementing the threshold.*

*(N shall be less than 101, and M less than 30), initialize all weights randomly between −0.5 ≤ wn,m ≤ +0.5*

*Implement further the possibilities to train the Perzeptron using the perzeptron learning rule with patterns ( pX, pY ) that have been read in from a file named PA-A-train.dat (P shall be less than 200), and a possibility to read in the weights wn,m from a file.*

The thing is- I don't understand that data- it looks like the numbers following the space are supposed to be a label, but- if so, why are there two? Shouldn't the label be only one?

Maybe someone can help me make sense of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural network can have arbitrary number of output neurons. In particular, when one has no hidden layer, training M-output perceptron is equivalent to training M binary perceptrons. So your data is quite easy - you have M=2 output variables, each is the expected value on a particular output neuron.

Comment: I realized that after considering it for a while. Do you know how can I implement that in java? Do you have any resources about that?

Comment: Just google it, this is very basic problem and dozens of tutorials and implementations available.

Comment: It's sort of confusing though, because I think- for the case of one output we have 1 label, and then it's easy to get the difference between the prediction and the true label, but in the case of two... I don't know- it's not so straight forward

Comment: you have one difference for one of the "labels" - and you use it to compute updates for weights **connected to this neuron**, and other error, independently, for updates of weights connected to it. Do not overthink that :-)

Comment: so I can consider it like actually I'm implementing two perceptrons--> one of them takes the inputs and uses for instance, the first label, the other takes the same inputs but uses the second label, like that?

Comment: When there is no hidden layer - yes, you are actually implementing two independent perceptrons.